# Qual a diferença em definir uma variável usando "val" somente e uma usando "lazy"?

Tags: scala

Estou estudando Scala e econtrei alguns códigos onde várias variáveis são definidas com a sintaxe "lazy".
Mesmo lendo alguns materiais em inglês, não consegui chegar a uma definição clara. 
Qual a diferença entre usar lazy e não usar?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza variáveis lazy a operação que define a variável só é executada no momento em que você utilizar a variável. Variáveis normais possuem o seu valor calculado assim que você as define.

```
val a = 10
//nesse momento a variável a já está com valor definido na memória

lazy val b = a + 1 
//nesse momento a variável b não está com valor definido na memória

val c = b + 1
//nesse momento é verificado que b ainda não foi calculado,
//então é realizado o cálculo a + 1 e o resultado salvo em b,
//por fim é definido o valor de c
```

A utilização de valores lazy não se limita somente a linguagem Scala, várias linguagens de programação utilizam esse mesmo conceito e ele pode ser muito útil para otimizar seu código.

Se quiser saber mais vale a pena dar uma olhada:

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading
https://blog.mxcursos.com/como-aumentar-a-velocidade-da-pagina-com-lazy-loading/